# update record if exist else create new record based by id in loopback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

i'm trying to update record if exist else i want to create new record,
i tried findById function but when i try to add new record inside it present this error :
create() is not a function ..
here is my code :

```js
Userpost.isMyPost = function (data , req, cb) {
  Userpost.findById(data.id, (err, Userpost) => {
    if (!err && Userpost) {
      Userpost.create({
        U_ID: "1" , 
        imageUrl: "ss" , 
        userLike : "aa" , 
        sharedFrom: "ss", 
        isDeleted : false , 
        isFav : true
      }, function(err, Userpost) {
        cb(err , Userpost);
      });
    } else {
      cb (err, {});
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've overridden  `Userpost` model with the returned data-value, so you don't have `.create()` and all other methods on it.
Try to replace `(err, Userpost) => ...` with some difference variable name e.g. `(err, data) => ...`. in your `findById` callback function

Comment: it's working fine ..
thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've overridden `Userpost` model with the returned data-value, so you don't have `.create()` and all other methods on it.

Try to replace `(err, Userpost) => ...` with some difference variable name e.g. `(err, response) => ....` in your `findById` callback function:

Example:

```js
Userpost.isMyPost = function (data , req, cb) {
  Userpost.findById(data.id, (err, response) => {
    if (!err && response) {
      Userpost.create({
        U_ID: "1" , 
        imageUrl: "ss" , 
        userLike: "aa" , 
        sharedFrom: "ss", 
        isDeleted: false , 
        isFav: true
      }, function(err, response) {
        cb(err, response);
      });
    } else {
      cb(err, {});
    }
  });
}
```